# How can I find external table in hive and hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, centos, hive

First I installed hadoop 2.6.0 on centos 
(reference path, and configuration 
http://www.rexamine.com/2015/02/installing-hadoop-2-6-0-on-centos-7/)

Installed hive and configure `hive-default.xml`

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.connectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db:create=true</value>
```

-->> (changed)

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.connectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/opt/hive(HIVE_HOME)metastore_db:create=true</value>
```

and I used data (https://github.com/reillywatson/nasdaq-outliers) `nasdaq_daily_prices_*.csv` file to create external table
(`stock.hql`)

```
create external table if not exists stocks(
...
location /user/hadoop/stock)
```

and I executed

```
hive -f stock.hql
```

and I executed too

```
bin/hive - e "describe extended stocks"
```

but hive return "table not found".

So how can I find external table and use it in hive and hadoop?

p.s My hadoop configuration is same in

```
http://www.rexamine.com/2015/02/installing-hadoop-2-6-0-on-centos-7/
```

and hive configuration is just changed

```
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/opt/hive(HIVE_HOME)metastore_db:create=true</value>


HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
HIVE_HOME=/opt/hive
```

Comment: Seems to be problem in your metastore connection string(jdbc) make sure that the metasstore service are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your table names. You created a table called `stocks` and are trying to describe a table called `stock`

Comment: sorry "describe extended stock" is miss type 
i executed  "describe extended stocks"